# How can I pass one NSInteger parameter at a time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop

I need to pass myInteger to a parameter one at a time and not to pass another myInteger until syncDocFinish function is done being called. So basically this code will be called once `[self syncDocs:myInteger];`  then it will not be called again until the `syncDocs` function is done.

```
 - (void) syncDocs
 {
int i;
for (i = 0; i < [mFormList count]; i++) {   
    myInteger = i;
    [self syncDocs:myInteger];  
}
 }

-(void)syncDocs : (NSInteger) myInt{

[docHandler getDocs:myInt limit:InitLoad_Count];

// the doc handler will call syncDocFinish automatically
 }


 - (void) syncDocFinish : (id) result
 {

 /// do functions{
  }
 /// sync doc is finished insert code to call [self syncDocs:myInteger];  again

    }
```

Comment: [Operation Queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html).

Comment: I don't understand what you are actually asking.

Comment: This is rather bad design for what you are doing. You may use delegate or notifications for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int myInteger = 0; // initialise as class level local variable

-(void)syncDocs {

    [docHandler getDocs:myInteger limit:InitLoad_Count];

    // the doc handler will call syncDocFinish automatically
}
- (void) syncDocFinish : (id) result {

     // do functions{
     //}
     /// sync doc is finished insert code to call [self syncDocs:myInteger]; 

if(myInteger < [mFormList count]){
  myInteger ++;
  [self syncDocs];   
}
}
This should be work...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply make use of BOOL value for the same.

BOOL isSyncDocFinish;

```
   - (void) syncDocs
 { 
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < [mFormList count]; i++) {   
    myInteger = i;
    if(isSyncDocFinish)
    {
     isSyncDocFinish = NO;
     [self syncDocs:myInteger]; 
    } 
  }
}

       -(void)syncDocs : (NSInteger) myInt
        {

         [docHandler getDocs:myInt limit:InitLoad_Count];

        // the doc handler will call syncDocFinish automatically
        }


      - (void) syncDocFinish : (id) result
        {
             isSyncDocFinish = YES;
      /// do functions{
        }
       /// sync doc is finished insert code to call [self syncDocs:myInteger];  again

   }
```

Comment: I don't think this works. The loop is incrementing i nevertheless the value of `isSyncDocFinish`. Therefore this could result in a lot of values which aren't passed to the method at all.

Comment: @dasdom as mentioned in OP's question > "then it will not be called again until the syncDocs function is done." the above block of code should work

Comment: This will not work..on the next iteration it just skip the if and that's it

Answer (score -1):

There're several solutions for the task like this:

1. Delegates
2. Notifications
3. NSOperationQueue with dependent operations
4. dispatch semaphores

I won't describe these in details because there's lots of information about it in the Internet.
 I would recommend to search for "how to use NSOperation dependencies" or read this [NSOperation howto](http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/)

Comment: better you could post the links for the same. and the way of doing it.

Comment: This is very easy to find..I wont spend time for the trivial things like this. He is newbie and he must learn how to use SO - 1. google 2. ask